# Búsqueda de (brechas|huecos|saltos) en secuencias numéricas

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo un método que asigna el siguiente número dependiendo de los números de fila que hay en la base de datos, lo que me parece que es gastar recursos por gastar y me gustaría cambiarlo, pero no he localizado en la documentación algo que me permita hacerlo. Utilizo XAMPP con mysql para las pruebas.

El método abre la conexión con la base de datos, realiza la sentencia SELECT * FROmM tabla; posteriormente se  guarda en un ResultSet con un bucle WHILE se recorren todas las filas, se coge el último número introducido, se le suma uno y se asigna a un jTextField para que introduzca el siguiente. Lo que me parece absurdo imaginando que puede haber más de 1000 filas me gustaría cambiar la sentencia por un SELECT count(codigo) FROM tabla; y así me cuente directamente cuantas filas hay y sume uno. Esto me presenta dos problemas: el primero es que si alguna fila ha sido borrada tendré problemas ya que se intentará insertar un número que es clave primaria repetido, el segundo problema es que no quiero utilizar ResultSet para no tener que recorrer todas las filas.

Una solución sería buscar si el número ya ha sido introducido, pero volvemos al problema de que tendrá que recorrer todas las filas y es lo que quiero evitar.

¿Se os ocurre como hacer más eficiente este método?

```
   private void asignarCodigo() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    //Cargo driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //Creo conexión
    Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(ruta, usuario, pass);
    //Creo sentencia
    Statement sentencia = cnx.createStatement();

    //Ejecuto sentencia sobre un resultset
    ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tabla;");
    //Variable para saber e ltamaño de ResultSet
    int ultimo = 0;
    //Recorro el bucle para saber el último código de departamento
    while (resultado.next()) {
        ultimo = resultado.getInt(1);
    }
    // Sumo uno al último código de departamento 
    ultimo++;
    //Asigno el nuevo id al campo de texto
    jTextFieldCodigo.setText(String.valueOf(ultimo));
    //Libero recursos
    ////resultado.close();
    sentencia.close();
    cnx.close();

}
```

Tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que estás buscando [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29736658/8663418). Por favor, si resuelve tu problema, publica una auto-respuesta con los detalles. Un saludo :-)

Comment: `SELECT Coalesce(Max(codigo), 0) FROM tabla` te va a traer el número más grande de la columna `codigo` ó 0 (cero) si no hay registros.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ambas respuestas son válidas. Aun que el enlace que pasa Trauma tiene una consulta maravillosa. Nunca se me hubiera ocurrido tal consulta, es excelente. Ahora publico la respuesta poniendo la resolución. Muchas gracias a los dos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a Trauma y a Damián Alva por sus respuestas, ambas son válidas pero cumplen diferentes objetivos.

La primera y más sencilla es utilizar: SELECT Coalesce(Max(codigo), 0) FROM tabla  esta sentencia nos devolverá el código máximo que hay en la tabla, le podemos sumar uno y tendremos el siguiente.

Pero en la explicación que hay en el enlace que comparte Trauma se explica una consulta que busca las brechas que pueda haber en la clave primaria (código en mi caso). Y así rellenar huecos por si se borraron filas.

Enlace a la explicación completa: [Explicación](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=es&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&tl=es&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340793/how-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbering-in-mysql/29736658&xid=17259,15700023,15700186,15700191,15700253,15700256,15700259&usg=ALkJrhicMK0mOayDawqN1voWcuKKbKtulw#29736658)

La consulta la he modificado para mi proyecto quedando el siguiente resultado:

```
SELECT (t1.codigo + 1) as  inicio_brecha, 
 (SELECT MIN(t3.codigo) -1 FROM tabla t3 WHERE t3.codigo> t1.codigo) as fin_brecha 
 FROM tabla t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT t2.codigoFROM tabla t2 WHERE t2.codigo= t1.codigo+ 1) ;
```

Esta consulta buscará las brechas que tengamos en el identificador (en mi caso código que es clave primaria), para rellenar los huecos. La he probado en Oracle SQL Developer sobre el esquema HR para poder comprobar el resultado devuelto, siendo éste una tabla con dos campos el campo que indica el inicio de la brecha y el que lo finaliza. Tendremos tantas tuplas como brechas tengamos.

[image: Comprobación sentencia SQL en Oracle SQL developer]

Posteriormente he adaptado la sentencia a mi proyecto, modificando el método, el resultado es el siguiente:

```
    private void asignarCodigo() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    //Cargo driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //Creo conexión
    Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(ruta, usuario, pass);
    //Creo sentencia
    Statement sentencia = cnx.createStatement();

    //Ejecuto sentencia para identificar las brechas en el codigo
    ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT (t1.codigo +1) as inicio_brecha, "
            + "(SELECT MIN(t3.codigo) -1 "
            + "FROM tabla t3 "
            + "WHERE t3.codigo > t1.codigo) as fin_brecha "
            + "FROM tabla t1 "
            + "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.codigo FROM tabla t2 WHERE t2.codigo = t1.codigo + 1)");
    //Movemos el "puntero" 
    resultado.next();
    //Guardamos el resultado de la primera columna, que es el inicio de la brecha, teniendo en cuenta que las tuplas se crean según las brechas no es necesario nada más
    int ultimo = resultado.getInt(1);

    //Asigno el nuevo id al campo de texto
    jTextFieldCodigo.setText(String.valueOf(ultimo));
    //Libero recursos
    sentencia.close();
    cnx.close();
}
```

Sin duda una magnifica solución para auto asignar la clave primaria. Muchas gracias por las respuestas y espero que os sea de utilidad.